# How do I stick to the button right in header using styled components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to that button right but I don't know how. Can someone help me? I've tried `position:right` on `HomeButton` but it didn't help. Here is my codes:

**Header.styles.js**

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Wrapper = styled.div`
    display:flex;
    background-color: #a86332;
    padding: 1%;
`
export const Title = styled.h1`
    color: white;
    margin:0;
`
export const HomeButton = styled.button`
    border:2;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color:#a86000;
    border-color:white;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition-duration:250ms;
    &:hover{
        height: 70px;
        width: 70px;
        margin:0 0 0 0;
        color:black;
        background-color:white;
        border-color: red;
    }
`
```

**Header.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { HomeButton, Title, Wrapper } from './Header.styles'


const Header = () => {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <Title>McKing Burger</Title>
            <HomeButton >Home</HomeButton>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

export default Header
```

**Screen shot[image]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your issue ;

```
export const Wrapper = styled.div`
        display:flex;
        background-color: #a86332;
        padding: 1%;
       justify-content: space-between;
    `
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

```
export const Wrapper = styled.div`
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between;
background-color: #a86332;
padding: 1%;`
```

just only add "justify-content" property to Wrapper style. :)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Give space between each item with `justify-content: space-between`

```
export const Wrapper = styled.div`
    display:flex;
    background-color: #a86332;
    padding: 1%;
    justify-content: space-between;
`
```

or add `align-self: flex-end` to the button.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by applying these CSS rules to the wrapper:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Using display flex like this:

```
export const Wrapper = styled.div`
    display:flex;
    background-color: #a86332;
    padding: 1%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
`
```

It will take both the Title and the home button and separate them, leaving the title on the left and the button on the right :)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it through several ways.

First through `justify-content: space-between;`

```
export const Wrapper = styled.div`
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
`
```

Second through `right:0` :

```
 export const Wrapper = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right:0;
 `
```

Third through this way `justify-content: flex-end;`

```
export const Wrapper = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
     `
```